# Validation rule is not working properly- the user should be able to select quantites for only one ticket type

Tags: php, laravel

I have the form below where the user can select the quantities that he want for each ticket type. Each ticket type has a min and maximum value and the user should only select allowed values, so I have a custome rule below.

The issue is that, for example when the user acesses the form to select the quantities that he wants for each ticket type, if the conference has 4 ticket types and he select quantities, for example the quantity "1", for only one ticket type and click "Next" it appears the validation message "You can only select the quantities available in the select menu". Only if the user select quantities for all ticket types the validation error dont appears.

But the user should be able to only select quantities for one ticket type. Do you know what is the issue?

Custom Rule:

```
class TicketTypeQuantity implements Rule{
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
       foreach($value as $key=>$v){
            $ttype = TicketType::where('name',$key)->first();
            if ( $v < $ttype->min || $v > $ttype->max)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'You can only select the quantities available in the select menu';
    }
}
```

Form where the user can select the quantity for each product.

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('congresses.storeQuantity', ['id' => $cong->id, 'slug' => $cong->slug])}}">
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
          @foreach($ttypes as $ttype)
              <li class="list-group-item">
                      <span>{{$ttype->name}}</span>
                  </div>
                  <select class="custom-select form-control" name="ttypes[{{ $ttype->name }}]">
                      <option selected></option>
                      @for ($i = $ttype->min; $i <= $ttype-> max; $i++)
                          <option value="{{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</option>
                      @endfor
                  </select>
                  <span>{{$ttype->showPrice()}}</span>
              </li>
          @endforeach
  </ul>
  <input type="submit" class="float-right btn btn-primary" value="Next" />
  </form>
```

storeQuantity method:

```
public function storeQuantity(Request $request, $id, $slug = null){
        $request->validate([
            'ttypes' => ['required', 'array', new TicketTypeQuantity ],
        ]);

        $ttypeQuantities = $request->get('ttypes');

        $all_participants = Congress::where('id', $id)->first()->all_participants;

        foreach($ttypeQuantities as $ttypeName => $quantity){

            $ttype = TicketType::where('name', $ttypeName)->firstOrFail();
            $price = $ttype->price;

            $selectedTypes[$ttype->name]['quantity'] = $quantity;
            $selectedTypes[$ttype->name]['price'] = $price;
            $selectedTypes[$ttype->name]['subtotal'] = $price * $quantity;
        }
        Session::put('selectedTypes', $selectedTypes);
        Session::put('all_participants' , $all_participants);
        return redirect(route('congresses.registration',['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]));
    }
```

Comment: share your controller with us. Then  it will be easier to debug.

Comment: I update the question.

Comment: when you `dd($ttype)` you get the correct object

Comment: In the storeQuantity()?

Comment: no in `TicketTypeQuantity`

Comment: yes, it appears "TicketType {#266 ▼
  #fillable: array:9 [▶]
  #dates: array:2 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:12 [▶]
  #original: array:12 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}".

Comment: The "foreach($value as $key=>$v){
            dd($value);" shows "array:3 [▼
  "ticketype1" => null
  "ticketype2" => null
  "ticketype3" => "1"
]", when only is selected the quantity 1 for the ticket type "ticketype3" and nothing for the other ticket types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're looping through the selected values you haven't explicitly allowed to have `nullable` values so you will need to modify your condition to allow `nullable` values like so:

```
if ( ($v < $ttype->min || $v > $ttype->max) && $v != null)
```

you can omit the selected values that have null value like so:

```
foreach($ttypeQuantities as $ttypeName => $quantity){
  if($quantity) {
    // your code goes here
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks after the user click in "Next" he goes to the registration.blade.php page where there is a sumamry of the selected ticket types and there is this code "@foreach($selectedTypes as $k=>$selectedType)
  <li>
      <span>{{$k}}</span>
      <span>{{$selectedType['quantity']}}</span>
      <span>{{ number_format($selectedType['price'], 2)}}€</span>
      <span>{{ number_format($selectedType['subtotal'], 2)}}€</span>
  </li>
@endforeach" to show the summary.

Comment: The issue is that it should only appear in the summary the ticket types selected by the user, but are appearing all ticket types, do you know why? That is the null ticket types should not appear in the summary.

Comment: I can't understand your full logic here but what i've noticed you need to check before you sending any data to the view or to be precise you need to filter your data. Sorry if that seems not helpful advice.